# how to design properties file/s in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a solution for a key/value property file in angular 5.
In JSF I had property file and I've just load it for the whole application.

I've used it like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#messages[xx:strcat('company.trip',trip.type.toString(),'.name')]}"/>
```

In the property file I had something like:

```
company.trip.HOLIDAY.name=Holiday trip type
```

In angular, i18n is the solution provided out of the box, BUT, the xlf files look inflated (too long).

I'm not sure if I can use key/value solution because my key is dynamic and Angular require something like:

```
<trans-unit id="f65253954b66e929a8b4d5ecaf61f9129f8cec64" datatype="html">
        <source>Dashboard</source>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">app/manager/header/header.component.ts</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">28</context>
        </context-group>
      </trans-unit>
```

Is it possible to use the trans-unit id for key (ie. 'company.trip.HOLIDAY.name' ) ? and in the html provide the key ONLY instead the text ?

Comment: All objects are keyed collections so you have a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Have you looked at using `ngx-translate` for i18n? http://www.ngx-translate.com